# a challenging example from negative binomial

Tags: probability

I found this from a text.

> Reuben rolls a die and whenever he gets a one or a six he receives  a token. The game ends when he has received $y$ tokens; he then gets $\$x$ , where $x$ is the number of rolls he made.

(a) Given that  $P(X = 6) = 40/729$. Find $y$.
(b) What is the variance of the Casino's profit if they make $\$3$ per game?
This is clearly a NB$(y,1/3)$; and I got $y = 4$; how do I incorporate this in variance calculation ?

`

Answer (score 0):

Great, you found that $X\sim\text{NB}(y=4, p = 2/6)$ on  $\{1,2,3\dotsc\}$. Now, (I think) they tell you that a player **pays** \$3 to play. Thus, the casino's profit $C$ is
$$C=\text{\$Price to play}-\text{\$Player winnings} = \$3-\$X$$
Thus the variance of the casino's profit is
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(C) &= \text{Var}(3-X)\\
&=(-1)^2\text{Var}(X)\\
&=\frac{4\cdot(2/6)}{4/6}\\
&=2
\end{align*}
So the variance of the profit is $2$.